# How to remove the shadow (outline) of text in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, text

After much trying  tutorials and googling how to remove the black outlines of text in Inkscape (I think it's the "stroke"), I have no luck. I would just like to make a few designs for different color t-shirts and the outlines are in my way, meaning I would just like to have the "fill" of the text to remain.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. It depends how it was constructed. It could be a simple stroke, or it could be something more complex. Is it a vector image? Is it a raster image?  It's difficult to say much more without seeing it. Can you share the SVG over at SVGshare.com and post the link here?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'm not really sure about the image types since I'm a beginner... Basically every letter in any font  that I write has an outline of stroke around it, before i save and export it everytime. Is there any known way at all of getting rid of the outline that the fonts have in any case?

Comment: It sounds like you do have a stroke set on the text.  Select the text box, then open the Fill and Stroke panel using Shift+Ctrl+F. You can change fills and strokes in there.

Comment: You can also go into Edit > Preferences > Tools > Text, and make sure to set the Style of New Objects [as shown here](https://imgur.com/H2qdgsP). That way your text tool won't ever change its default style accidentally.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! Just one thing, do you know how to change the value of the "Unset" value in the preferences? I go across it and click on it and it doesn't change...

Comment: Make sure you have some text set without a stroke first (delete it in the Fill and Stroke panel), and make sure the text box is selected, then when you go into the preferences, hit the button that says Take From Selection.  Inkscape should put the currently selected text's stroke and fill settings into there so it remembers it as the default.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Billy Kerr! I managed to make it work. It seems like it is just a matter of setting the stroke paint to no paint aswell. You really helped me today! Thank you!

Comment: I've added this as an answer now  that I know what was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a stroke set on your text. There are  couple of ways to fix this.

Make sure the text box is selected, then open the Fill and Stroke Panel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. This is where you can delete or change strokes and fills. Select the Stroke Paint tab. The X button on the left will delete the stroke completely. Similarly to change the fill, go into the fill tab.

[image]

You can also fix the problem with the Text Tool acting in unexpected ways. If you go into *Edit > Preferences > Tools > Text*, you can set the Style of New Objects setting to **This tools own Style**. This will mean the default will always be the same, so even if you set a stroke, the tool will return to its default next time you use it.

If the option in there has a stroke set, you can select some text that has no stroke and hit the button that says "Take from Selection". That will store it as the default.

[image]

Comment: It all works nicely... Thank you so much for your help! Sincerely.

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t working for me, I’ve tried both and her I choose “union” for the text it hours from solid black to an outline!