# Inkscape Showing all Fonts as Thick Bubble Letters

Tags: inkscape, fonts

Inkscape 1.2.2 is displaying all the default fonts as unreadable and very big undefined letters similar to bubble letters. This happened on my original install of inkscape on Win 11, then I uninstalled inskcape and reinstalled it. The problem continues. The only information I have found on this issue is related to custom installed fonts sometimes causing problems, my problem however is based on a fresh install and using all the default fonts. [image]

Comment: Just a guess..... some stroke or effect is applied.

Comment: You have a stroke set on the text. Same issue as [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/159970/89608).

Comment: I am closing this question as a duplicate for now since everything you have given us points to this being the solution. If it isn’t, please [edit] your question.